# getName() from class Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Why do I have access to the `getName()` method? My class doesn't extends the class `Thread` just implements the interface `Runnable`.

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread is running");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyThread thread1 = new MyThread();
        Thread thr = new Thread(thread1, "thread");
        thr.start();
        System.out.println(thr.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println(thr.getName());//Why do I have access to this method?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not calling getName() on an instance of the MyThread class, you're calling it on an instance of the Thread class. You should consider renaming your class to MyRunnable because MyThread would seem like your class is some sort of Thread class, while it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Every action you perform is in a thread. In case you are doing some action, in the main method while starting the program, it happens in the main thread.

The method currentThread is static, and it provides the thread that is currently executing that line and when you perform, getName() it is on that Thread object.